# React/Node Trouble sending ImageData to server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, canvas, redux, imagedata

I have a problem where i have some issues to send canvas's imageData to my server to process it.

Here's my react/redux action to send data:

```
export const edit = (e) => dispatch => {
  let payload = store.getState().image.imageData
  payload = payload[payload.length-1]
  console.log(payload)
  const id = e.target.id ? e.target.id : e.target.parentElement.id
  fetch(`/api/editing/${id}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    // headers: {
    //   "Content-Type": "application/json"
    // },
    body: JSON.stringify({ imgData: payload })
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    dispatch({ type: UPDATE_IMAGE, payload: json.imgData })
    // handle response display
  })
}
```

Here's my how I handle request:

```
const traitement = require('../../processing/traitement')

router.post('/:type', (req, res) => {
  const { imgData } = req.body
  const method = req.params.type
  const imgDataProcessed = traitement[method](imgData)
  return res.status(200).json({ imgData: imgDataProcessed })
})
```

Here's an example of what a treatment method looks like:

```
negatif: function(imgData) {
  console.log(imgData)
  var n = imgData.data.length;
  for(i=0; i<n; i+=4){
    imgData.data[i] = 255 - imgData.data[i];
    imgData.data[i+1] = 255 - imgData.data[i+1];
    imgData.data[i+2] = 255 - imgData.data[i+2];
    imgData.data[i+3] = 255;        
  }
  return imgData;
},
```

the console.log() just before I send (what I expect to send):

```
ImageData {data: Uint8ClampedArray(180000), width: 300, height: 150}
data: Uint8ClampedArray(180000) [0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 
  255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 
  255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 
  0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 
  255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 
  0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 
  255, …]
height: 150
width: 300
__proto__: ImageData
```

I can't paste what I get from the server but I lose the width, height keys, the typeof is Object instead of ImageData and the data key is typeof Object instead of Uint8ClampedArray.

So my question is: How can I do to make my route access the same data I send so I can be able to process it?

As you can see I send them as stringified json and I have a json bodyparser middleware on my server, maybe it's from there.
I also though about the content-type header

EDIT:
Thanks to Kaiido I've modified my code that way which seems to work at 1 exception

How I modified my code, front:

```
  let payload = store.getState().image.imageData
  payload = payload[payload.length-1]
  const id = e.target.id ? e.target.id : e.target.parentElement.id;
  console.log(payload)
  const meta = {
    width: payload.width,
    height: payload.height
  }
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("meta", JSON.stringify(meta));
  formData.append("data", new Blob([payload.data.buffer]))
  fetch(`/api/editing/${id}`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData
  })
  .then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
  .then(buffer => {
    console.log(buffer)
    const data = new Uint8ClampedArray(buffer)
    console.log(data.length)
    const newImg = new ImageData(data, payload.width, payload.height)
    return newImg
  })
```

back:

```
router.post('/:type', (req, res) => {
  let form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    fs.readFile(files.data.path, (err, data) => {
      const imgProcessed = traitement[req.params.type](data)
      console.log(imgProcessed.length)
      return res.status(200).json([imgProcessed])
    })
  })
})
```

1 issue left: assuming that for testing I'm using a 150*300px image my data array should be 180000 long (300*150*4) which it is until I send server's response.
When the front receives response it calls `res.arrayBuffer()`
then it creates a new Uint8ClampedArray but then my length is no more 180000 but 543810 in that case.
As Kaiido said I might want to slice that array, which I tried, but doesn't works.

How should I slice it? 180000 firsts ones? 180000 lasts ones? some other way?

Comment: Have you tested your API using Postman? Are the routes working and receiving proper data?

Comment: No, not with postman but directly with the front, the problem is that is that is receive data but not the exact data i sent (as i said in my post)

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
const { imgData } = JSON.parse(req.body)
```

this is the reverse of `JSON.stringify` and needed as you are sending data via stringify but in route not parsing it back to Original Object.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i think i'm already doing it, i have bodyParser middleware above my route: `app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }))` that does the same thing ? EDIT: tested it got the error `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` wich means it has already been parsed..

Comment: Right, you should check `req.body.imgData` as while sending you are passing `Json.Stringify({ imgData : payload }) instead of simple `Json.Stringify(payload). ImgData is a object inside body that contains payload.

Comment: Also better to un comment the Header. `Console.log()` before sending is fine. Have you checked `Console.log` on route? You seem to be losing data during transfer.

Comment: Yes i was doing testing that's why it was commented. Yes i know, the thing is that i lose data (my height/width keys) and my array (imageData.data) becomes a key/pair object and both of them lose their type to become objects

Answer (score 1):

JSON only has very few types it handles: Strings, Numbers, Arrays, Objects, Booleans and null.

An ImageData, which has no enumerable properties will get *JSON.stringified* to `"{}"`, an empty object.

```js
const img = new ImageData(6, 6);
img.data.fill(0xFF);
console.log('JSON', JSON.stringify(img)); // "{}"

const props = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(img);
console.log('own properties', props); // {}
```

You'll loose all informations.
So to circumvent this, you'd have to send all these manually in your request.
Sounds quite easy to simply move the needed values to an other object:

```js
const img = new ImageData(6,6);
const dataholder = (({width, height, data}) => ({width, height, data}))(img);

console.log(JSON.stringify(dataholder));
```

However, you'll notice that `data` property is not stringified in a proper way.

Indeed, a TypedArray when *JSON.stringified* is converted to a simple object, with all its indexes set as keys.
And what should have taken only 144 bytes to represent our 6px*6px image data now takes 1331 bytes.

```js
const typedArray = new Uint8ClampedArray(6*6*4).fill(0xFF);

console.log(JSON.stringify(typedArray));

const as_string = new Blob([JSON.stringify(typedArray)]);
const as_arraybuffer = new Blob([typedArray]);

console.log('as string', as_string.size, 'bytes');
console.log('as arraybuffer', as_arraybuffer.size, 'bytes');
```

I'll let you do the Maths for bigger images, but you might consider an other approach...

---

Instead of sending a stringified version of this Uint8ClampedArray, you'd better **send its underlying ArrayBuffer.** That may sound like more code for you to write, but you'll save bandwidth, and maybe even trees.

So to send your ImageData to your server, you'll do

```js
const img = new ImageData(6, 6);
img.data.fill(0xFF);

const meta = {
  width: img.width,
  height: img.height
  // add more metadata here if needed
};
const formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("meta", JSON.stringify( meta ))
formdata.append("data", new Blob([img.data.buffer]));

console.log(...formdata); // [key, value], [key, value]
// here data is a File object and weights only 144 bytes

/* // send the formdata to your server
fetch('yoururl', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formdata
})
.then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
... // we'll come to it later
*/
```

Now on your server, in order to retrieve all the parts of your request, you'll have [to grab the form-data content](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-handle-multipart-form-data/), and access the image's data as a File upload.

You'll then have to read this uploaded file (e.g using `fs.readFile(temp_path)` and do the manips from the returned Buffer directly (since [Buffers in node are Uint8Array](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_typedarray)).

Once your manips are done, you can send directly this modified Buffer as a response.

Now on front, you'll just have to ask for the Response to be consumed as an ArrayBuffer, and to generate a new ImageData from this ArrayBuffer:

```
//... see above
fetch('yoururl', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formdata
})
// request as ArrayBuffer
.then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
.then(buffer => {
  // create a new View over our ArrayBuffer
  const data = new Uint8ClampedArray(buffer);
  const new_img = new ImageData(data, img.width, img.height);
  return new_img;
});
```

Here it is assuming that your front doesn't need metadata from server response (because you already have it).
If you are in a case where you need some metadata, then you can prepend it at the beginning of your ArrayBuffer response (assign a slot to let you know its size, then *slice()* your received Array in order to grab both the metadata and the actual image data.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to to explain me, with your help i'm close to making it works. just an issue left wich i explain on my edit. If you have a bit more time for me, take a look t it